# Why position fixed reduced the width in react?

Tags: reactjs, css, react-redux, material-ui

Why my side bar width is reduced when I used `position:fixed` ? Here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/1yr3nlqp74

steps to reproduce bug

1. open the code in `new window` (full screen)
2. see pic before and after using `position :fixed`

before using position
[image]
[image]

after using position
css issue in this line

```
 sideBar__block: {
    padding: 20,
    position: "fixed",
    top: "64px"
  },
```

Comment: why do you want to give it position. It's working fine without it

Comment: because it's shrink to fit ... it behaves like inline-block,

Comment: Does it have to be position fixed? - could you use position sticky instead. This will all depend on browsers that you want it to work on. If it has to be position fixed you could use javascript to work out the width of the container div that has the grey background then use javascript to apply a width to the fixed positioned div

Comment: If you want to use fixed position, then you need to apply the width as well.

Comment: Here is a bit of a hackie way of doing this apply `left: 0; right: 74%;` to `.sideBar__block` this means it will change the width as the item changes with position fixed. its a pure CSS way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

`Position:fixed;` will make the `div` the size of the largest piece of content unless a width is applied.

There are a few options that you can try.

With `width`

```
 sideBar__block: {
    padding: 20;
    position: fixed;
    top: 64px;
    width:21%;
  }
```

To make this flex with the page you can apply `left` and `right` positioning

```
 sideBar__block: {
    padding: 20;
    position: fixed;
    top: 64px;
    left:0%;
    right:74%;
  }
```

For more modern browsers you can use [position:sticky](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_sticky)

```
 sideBar__block: {
    padding: 20;
    position: sticky;
    top: 64px;
  }
```

These options will all allow the fixed container to flex with the screen.

Answer (score 0):

"Position:fixed" will take the width depending up on content size. For more clarification try to increase the text in list items, you can observe the width of the sidebar also increases.